# Cortana doesn't respond anymore?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I got the November update a few days ago. At first, everything seemed to be great. Now however, Cortana doesn't reply to queries. So, if I say 'hi', it takes me to the Bing search result for 'hi' instead of responding with 'Hello!', as it usually does/did.

Comment: I earned the tumble weed badge because of this question... [Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.]